# Sugar ORM - android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table TABLE_NAME already exists

Tags: android, sugarorm

I am using [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) to save data in (local) SQLite DB. I am getting this exception every time? May I know why it is trying to create Table if already exist? How to avoid this?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`... Can you do that?

Comment: Sugar ORM is a mess... If you're not using it in production already, I would recommend to run and find a better lib or go with Realm.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not writing any query here..

Comment: Can you add your logcat here? Did you add `@Table` annotation on two classes of the same name? Forget to update the version value in the manifest? When are you seeing this error? Did it work before?